# Where is Homepage Background Photo?

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, widget, slider

I have taken over web development of [this site](https://merchantconcepts.com/) from a previous designer, who I am not in contact with. I am attempting to find where the team photo under the "You're In Good Hands" header is uploaded. The site is built with custom widgets, with the Top E widget hosting that header and the tab menu of the team members. However, there is no 'slider' widget that hosts the photo, as there is on the top suit photo (which is under the top a slider). There are also a number of custom plugins that I believe were created for design customization. I have looked in the CSS for all of the team-related plugins, but can't find anything. Even when I did a google search of the image, its not hosted anywhere on the Merchant Concepts site or another hosting location. Does anyone know where I can find and replace this file? I'm currently waiting on hosting info to access the FTP, but I am more a front end editor/ digital marketer, so any insight would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 3):

#### This is the image

https://merchantconcepts.com/wp-content/themes/boss/images/bg-about.png

#### This is the element

.tm-about-bg

(i.e. the div with class="... tm-about-bg")

#### This is where it is in your files

> https://merchantconcepts.com/wp-content/themes/boss/cache/theme-378dd14e.css
>   Line 359 onwards

```
.tm-about-bg:after { ...
    background-image: url(' :D ');
```

The :after refers to a CSS generated 'pseudo-element'.